# Two or more coditions are true skip record, continue to next

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following code:

```
([L_D]='mc' and [L_D]='mb' or [L_D]='f1' or [L_D]='fs' or [L_D]='f2' or [L_D]='f3' or [L_D]='ma' or [L_D]='m*' or [L_D]='f*' or [L_D]='**')
```

If this record has `L_D='MC'` and any of the other codes. Skip this record. Then return all records that `[L_D]='mc'`

I'm thinking a nested 'If statement' would work. But my results are not correct.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking for.   Is L_D from a detail table?   It looks like you can use a SUM with nested case statement, but without giving some clue as to the structure and result, it's hard to help.

Comment: Yes,L_D is from a table, (trdcode.L_D). The query returns hits, with this:

and (L_D='mc')

I get all records with L_D that have 'MC', but some of those records also include rows with 'F1', 'MA'.

What I would like, is to exclude all records that also have 'F1', 'MA', etc.

Example:

13067470 MA FirstName LastName
13067470 FS FirstName LastName
13067470 MC FirstName Lastname

The above listing would not be included in the query return.

Answer (score 1):

I'll presume that you have something like the following:

```
Customer
(
     id             Int IDENTITY,
     last_name      Varchar(40),
     first_name     Varchar(30),
)

CustomerEvents
(
     id             Int IDENTITY,
     cust_id        Int,
     l_d            Varchar(2)
)
```

In which case a query that would (appear to) satisfy your question would look like:

```
 SELECT CUST.id                AS cust_id,
        CUST.first_name,
        CUST.last_name,
   FROM Customer CUST
        INNER JOIN
        (
             SELECT cust_id, 
                   SUM ( CASE 
                            WHEN l_d = 'mc' THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                         END
                       )  AS  mc_count,
                    SUM( CASE
                           WHEN l_d in ('mb', 'fl', 'fs', 'f2',
                                        'f3', 'ma', 'm*', 'f*', '**' ) THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                         END 
                       )    AS other_count
             FROM CustomerEvents
                  GROUP BY cust_id
        ) CustScore
          ON CustScore.cust_id = CUST.id
  WHERE CustScore.mc_count > 0
    AND CustScore.other_count = 0
```

Comment: You should exclude `'mc'` from the `in` predicate's list. Otherwise your query will return nothing, because if `mc_count` yields 1 or more, `other_count` will be at least `1` too and so the `WHERE` clause will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @AndriyM    You're right.   I've fixed the code to reflect your comment.